# Messed up panels after plot.zoo (multiple) and par(new=T)

Tags: r, zoo, par

I created a six-panel plot with plot.zoo
and cleared my graphical settings with par(new = T). I expected the next six-panel plot to be "on top" of the other. The first panel however is missing (still on the old plot), only the 2-6 show up (but at the wrong position).
What else do I have to reset in addition to par(new = T)?

```
> require(PerformanceAnalytics) 
> data('managers') 
> managers <- managers[,c('HAM1','HAM3','HAM4','SP500 TR','US 10Y TR','US 3m TR')]
> plot.zoo(managers) 
> par(new = T) 
> plot.zoo(managers*1.1, col='red')
```

Answer (score 1):

`plot.zoo` does not support that on multipanel plots.  In general, it expects that you do it all in one call, possibly by specifying a `panel=` function.

Here are two approaches.  Note that `screens` is recycled in the first approach.

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(zoo)

data("managers")   
cn <- c('HAM1','HAM3','HAM4','SP500 TR','US 10Y TR','US 3m TR')
managers_z <- as.zoo(managers)

# 1. without a panel function
plot(cbind(managers_z[, cn], 1.1*managers_z[, cn]), screens = seq_along(cn),
  col = rep(c("black", "red"), each = length(cn)))

# 2. with a panel function
pnl <- function(x, y, ...) {
  lines(y ~ x, ...)
  dots <- list(...)
  dots$col <- "red"
  do.call(lines, c(1.1 * y ~ x, dots))
}
plot(managers_z[, cn], panel = pnl)
```

Also note that if you want to do it in multiple passes you can do it using `xyplot.zoo` like this:

```
library(lattice)

xyplot(managers_z[, cn])

for(i in seq_along(cn)) {
  trellis.focus("panel", 1, i)
  panel.lines(1.1 * managers_z[, cn[i]], col = "red")
  trellis.unfocus()
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution! Independent of plot.zoo, shouldn't par(new = T) reset everything (such that there is no information left regarding panels/screens)?

Comment: It is unsupported so what happens if you try to use it is undefined.